# How to understand notation in Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right in the theorem: Suppose $T\in L(V,W)$ and $v\in V$. Then $M(Tv)=M(T)M(v)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

In the book *Linear Algebra Done Right* by Axler, there is the following definition

> **Definition**: Suppose $v\in V$, where $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space, and $v_1,...,v_n$ is a basis of $V$. The matrix of $v$
> with respect to this basis is the $nx1$ matrix
>
> $$M(v)=\begin{bmatrix}c_1 \\ (...) \\ c_n\end{bmatrix}$$
>
> where $c_1,...,c_n$ are scalars such that
>
> $$v=c_1v_1+...+c_nv_n$$

Then he says

> The matrix $M(v)$ of a vector $v\in V$ depends on the basis
> $v_1,...,v_n$ of $V$ as well as on $v$. However, the basis should be
> clear from the context and thus it is not included in the notation.
>
> Occasionally we want to think of elements of $V$ as relabeled to be
> $n$-by-1   matrices. Once a basis $v_1,...,v_n$ is chosen, the
> function $M$ that takes $v\in V$ to $M(V)$ is an isomorphism of $V$
> onto $F^{n,1}$ that implements this relabeling, where $F$ is
> $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.

So it seems the same notation is being used to denote a matrix of a vector in $V$, and then a function from $V$ to $F^{n,1}$. In addition, there is yet a third use of the notation $M$, namely $M(T)$ where $T:V\to W$ is a linear map. In this third use $M(T)$ is an $m$ by $n$ matrix where the columns are the coordinates of a basis of $V$ in a basis of $W$, and the matrix is called the matrix of $T$ with respect to these bases.

Then there is the following theorem which says that "linear maps act like matrix multiplication"

> Theorem: Suppose $T\in L(V,W)$ and $v\in V$, where $V$ is a vector
> space and  $L(V,W)$ is the vector space of vector spaces from $V$ to
> $W$. Suppose $v_1,...,v_n$ is a basis of $V$ and $w_1,...,w_n$ is a
> basis of $W$. Then
>
> $$M(Tv)=M(T)M(v)\tag{1}$$

My question is about the notation used in this theorem. Is it the case that in (1) above each of the uses of $M$ is actually a different conceptual entity?

$Tv$ is a vector in $W$. $v$ is a vector in $V$.

$M(v)$ seems to be the matrix of $v$ with respect to a basis $B_v$ in $V$.

$M(T)$ seems to be the matrix of $T$ with respect to the aforementioned basis $B_v$ in $V$ and also some basis $B_w$ in $W$.

Finally, $M(Tv)$ is the matrix of vector $w=Tv\in W$ with respect to $B_w$.

After writing this out, it seems that perhaps I have understood the notation after all. But I would like to confirm this.

Also, even if I did understand now, is it really necessary for the notation to be this way? Why not add subscripts to the uses of $M$?

Comment: Yes if you want to be rigorous you can express $M(T)$ say as $M_{B_V}^{B_W}(T)$ where we have the operator $$
M_{B_V}^{B_W} : \mathcal{L}(V, W) \to \mathbb R^{\text{dim}(W) \times \text{dim}(V)}
$$ but expressing all this is clunky; hence the abuse of notation where things are expected to be understood from context